# Google Places ownership verification

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

I'm trying to verify the user's ownership of a Google place, restaurant and bars for now.

I checked this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108469/validate-google-place-ownership-via-api-oauth-sequence), but it's unanswered.

Basically, the app I'm creating needs the place owners to post on behalf of the place. I want to verify the association of the person posting and the place so that regular users can't post junk. Is there a *Google way* of doing it ? If not, what other methods do you think is possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817407/validate-place-owner-google-places-api?lq=1) if it can help you especially the issue that you can find in the answer.